# status of eclipse console on cmd

Tags: eclipse, jboss, cmd, status

Do we have any way to see the status (or traffic) of eclipse console on command line MSDOS, because I have two screen so I just want to view status of application when I have any action. i look like when I'm using JBOSS, and then I open MSDOS, I type standalone.bat, it's show me the status when running JBOSS. 
Thanks all.